# Repair-VirtualDisk remains in suspended

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, windows-server, virtual-disk

We erroneously added a P40 disk to our (marketplace) Azure Sql server / virtual machine.

We tried removing it following the process described in following articales

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/948241/storage-spaces-direct-cant-remove-physical-disk-fr

https://serverfault.com/questions/1117638/storage-spaces-with-azure-disk-how-can-we-extend-virtual-disks

We managed to get the Physical disk in a "Retired" state.
[image]

But after running "Repair-VirtualDisk -Friendlyname ", the job was added in a suspended state. And doesn't seem to run
[image]

Comment: Did you mean to ask this over on Server Fault?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure) for immediate help. Thanks!